# Why is echo statement not generating anything in my PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, web, lamp

In my code, I have javacript get the local time on the client side and post it to the server. On the post event, I have the following code in PHP.

```
<?php 
......
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
    ....
    if($fh = fopen("files/$fileID",'w'))
    {
        fwrite($fh, '<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>');
        echo '<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>';
        fclose($fh);
    }
    else
        echo "<span style=\"color:yellow\">Error creating file!</span>";
}
?>
```

The file is successfully created, and inside that file (for debugging, to just see what echo statement generates, I dumped the same string in that file) I can the following statement as well.

```
<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>
```

However, the message "Successfully created file" is not shown on the screen. This means the echo statement is not working. What could be the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: Try to `file_put_contents($fh, '<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

Comment: PHP is a server-side preprocessor. It can't change a file already being viewed by a client.

Comment: I put the string into a file just for debugging, to see what I echoed. But the problem remains that the echo statement itself doesn't display anything.

Comment: Can you show your javascript code?

Comment: How you are posting this to the server, Through ajax?

Comment: view your HTML source after execution, what does it reveal? use var_dump also; what are the results? if it shows up (in source), then it's a CSS issue. Look at your console also. @pythonic

Comment: If you do not process the answer, it will not be displayed. But I am pretty sure you can see it in your Browsers Development Console.

Comment: @Edu: Javascript is working fine. That is why the file creation code also executes. But how come the echo statement doesn't properly execute?

Comment: @pythonic ping me if what I said up there made any sense. I am closing this tab now since I've gotten no response. Maybe it was worthless, who knows.

Comment: `ob_flush();` and `flush();` before and after your code... tell me if it worked but my guess is that something is really wrong with your output buffers (php.ini stuff...)

Answer (score -2):

Just a tought: 
Try closing the file first.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
    ....
    if($fh = fopen("files/$fileID",'w'))
    {
        fwrite($fh, '<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>');
        fclose($fh);
        echo '<span style="color:yellow">Successfully created file!</span>';
    }
    else
        echo "<span style=\"color:yellow\">Error creating file!</span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: File was just for debugging. Echo statement itself doesn't work.